# Can't run ember test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

After many successful times running `ember test` and `ember test -s`, I can't run either of them on a specific project. The only thing I can think of that happened since it last ran successfully is that Terminal.app crashed while `ember test -s` was running.

Now when I run `ember test -s` on that project, I always get this error:

```
Global error: Error: Assertion Failed: The initializer 'container-debug-adapter' has 
already been registered at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 38210


Global error: Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your 
tests index.html includes "assets/tests.js". at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 38210


Error: Assertion Failed: The initializer 'container-debug-adapter' has already been 
registered at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 38210
Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests 
index.html includes "assets/tests.js". at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 38210
```

If I try running `ember test -s` on a different project, it works fine. So it seems to me that there must be something untracked by git that is sitting somewhere in the project folder that causes this problem.

- Ember: 3.14.1
- Ember CLI:

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then running `npm install`.

I wish that I understood what could cause this and why reinstalling all of my dependencies would fix it.

Comment: By deleting `package-lock.json` you were not only reinstalling the dependencies but also updating them. So it might have been fixed in a newer version.